# Passing values to in operator using subquery (dynamically) and also static value

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
Select 
    bp.id_plan 
from 
    b_plan bp 
left outer join 
    b_rate_category brc on bp.rate_code = brc.rate_code 
left outer join 
    b_rate_category_date brd on brc.id_ratecategory = brd.id_ratecategory   
where 
    bp.hotel = 21 
    and bp.rate_code in (Select bp.rate_code 
                         from b_plan bp 
                         inner join b_rate_category brc on bp.rate_code = brc.rate_code 
                         inner join b_rate_category_date brd on brc.id_ratecategory = brd.id_ratecategory 
                         where bp.hotel = 21 and brd.Date_planstatus between '2016-04-12' and '2016-04-14', 'None')
```

Trying select plans based on rate codes which are available for the date range and also need to select plans which has rate_code 'None', these plans(None) doesn't have date range. Here i am trying to put 'None' with rate codes which are returning by sub query

Comment: Please format! Mark code and click `{}`.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Why do GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was not much clear but do you want to do something like this?

```
Select 
bp.id_plan 
from 
b_plan bp 
left outer join 
b_rate_category brc on bp.rate_code = brc.rate_code 
left outer join 
b_rate_category_date brd on brc.id_ratecategory = brd.id_ratecategory   
where 
bp.hotel = 21 
and bp.rate_code in (Select bp.rate_code 
                     from b_plan bp 
                     left outer join b_rate_category brc on bp.rate_code = brc.rate_code 
                     left outer join b_rate_category_date brd on brc.id_ratecategory = brd.id_ratecategory 
                     where (bp.hotel = 21 and brd.Date_planstatus between '2016-04-12' and '2016-04-14') OR bp.rate_code = 'None')
```

Note an OR in the end of the sub query.

Comment: Can you relook into it? I made changes

Comment: Does you query executes without any syntax error? This comma (,) 'None' is grabbing my attention.

Comment: I have updated my query as per your changes. Please have a look. Your way would fail if your subquery returns more than one row.